# Memory usage xml Vs program

Tags: android, android-xml

I need to know the memory usage on 2 scenarios. 
1. Giving the visibility parameter from ImageButton in the XML
2. Programmatically controlling the visibility of ImageButton.

Could you please share your experience on which one will be a better in memory consumption ?

Comment: I think the xml will be always treated as static block. If you define it as the code, it can be non-static.

Comment: any comment on memory consumption ?

Comment: Yes, you're worrying about the wrong things.

Comment: @Simon you mean to say both the scenarios are same and there is no need to worry?

Comment: It would take a lot of effort to work out, but you're talking about a few bytes.